# Добавленная консоль в Win32 окно не выводит текст printf

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, консоль, printf

Здравствуйте! Создаю консоль такой функцией:

```
void ConsoleClass::CreateConsole(char *consoleName)
{
    int hConHandle = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    AllocConsole();
    SetConsoleTitle(consoleName);
    m_Console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(PtrToUlong(m_Console), 0);
    fp = _fdopen(hConHandle, "w");
    *stdout = *fp;
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
}
```

В окне, в функции WndProc, при нажатии на кнопку выполняю эту функцию и пишу printf("Hello %s\n", buffer). Консоль выводится, но данные не выводятся

Comment: а зачем Вы делаете все эти манипуляции с хендлами? Или где то скопипастили? Я бы после SetConsoleTitle больше ничего не выводил.

Comment: Если ничего не писать после SetConsoleTitle то все равно printf работать не будет. m_Console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); это нужно для записи через стандартную функцию WriteConsole, я туда хендл отправляю, а остальное скопипастил, оно в принципе не обязательно
Я записываю через WriteConsole сейчас, но это не удобно, когда нужно быстро узнать значение, потому что нужно для этой функции буфер создавать и в него что то записывать, а через printf это все быстрее делается

Comment: fp = _fdopen(hConHandle, "w");
*stdout = *fp;
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
Эта часть предназначена для перенаправления вывода на консоль(безбуферного вывода)